# Nested ForEach List

Tags: c#, foreach

Now i just get 1 questionID, how can i get all the associated questions id foreach item?

I want the item to output like this:
Item - Text = "itemTitle"
       Value = "questionID1, questionID2, questionID3 etc"

Thanks for answers

```
        string categoryId = "";
        string questionID = "";


        foreach (var item in searchList.resources)
        { 
                foreach (var associatedQuestion in item.associatedQuestions)
                {
                    categoryId = associatedQuestion.categoryid.ToString();

                    questionID = associatedQuestion.id.ToString();

                }

                myList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = item.linktext.ToString(), Value = categoryId + questionID  });

        }

        return System.Web.Helpers.Json.Encode(myList); 
    }
```

Comment: What is the value of searchList, associatedQuestion etc. Your question and code sample is vague

Comment: you reassign `categoryId` and `questionId` every iteration of the foreach so only the last one is used - move the `myList.Add` up 3 lines

Comment: Try using a Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>> for myList (instead of a list). This will give you all of the distinct values that go to a title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could for example use String.Join in combination with LINQ instead of your inner foreach Loop. Example:

```
foreach (var item in searchList.resources)
{ 
        //First convert all questionIds to a string collection
        IEnumerable<String> allQuestionIDs = item.associatedQuestions.Select(q => q.id.ToString());

        //Convert the collection to single comma seperated String
        string questionIdsString = String.Join(", ", allQuestionIDs);

        myList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = item.linktext.ToString(), Value = questionIdsString });
}
```